# How typeset a numeric table from a CSV file

Tags: tables, formatting, datatool

I have a CSV file (`db.txt`)like this:

```
30.0,   0.0,    0.0
60.0,   1.9098, 5.8779
90.0,   6.9098, 9.5106
120.0,  13.09,  9.5106
150.0,  18.09,  5.8779
180.0,  20.0,   0.0
```

I need to typeset it. My problem is related with the wrong alignment of decimal point and the number of decimals (must be a constant for each column):

```
\renewcommand*{\dtlrealalign}{r}

\DTLloaddb[
    noheader,
    keys={x,y,theta},
    headers={
        \shortstack{$\boldsymbol{\theta_{2,i}}$},
        \shortstack{X},
        \shortstack{Y}
             }
  ]{db}{db.txt}
\begin{table}[t]
  \caption{Database file}
  \centering
  \DTLdisplaydb{db}
\end{table}
```

[image: Table Snapshot]

Any advice, please?

Comment: Is a re-exporting of the csv file into a format that has decimal-aligned zeros a possibility?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `pgfplotstable` for this. If you load the `array` package, you can set the option `dec sep align` for `pgfplotstabletypeset` to get the alignment at the decimal point. Padding the numbers with zeros can be accomplished by setting `fixed zerofill`, the number of decimals can be set using `precision`, either for all columns or for individual columns by using `display column/<index>/precision=<digits>`.

[image: pgfplotstable and array]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}       % For the example data
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{array}      % For aligining at decimal point

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
theta, x, y
30.0,   0.0,    0.0
60.0,   1.9098, 5.8779
90.0,   6.9098, 9.5106
120.0,  13.09,  9.5106
150.0,  18.09,  5.8779
180.0,  20.0,   0.0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{testdata.csv}{\table}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    dec sep align,      % Align at decimal point
    fixed zerofill,     % Fill numbers with zeros
    precision=4,        % Set number of decimals
    display columns/0/.style={precision=1}, % Change for first column (column 0)
    ] {\table}
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `pgfplotstable` and the `siunitx` package to align the columns. I've used it here in conjunction with booktabs and properly formatted column headers:

[image: pgfplotstable and siunitx]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
theta, x, y
30.0,   0.0,    0.0
60.0,   1.9098, 5.8779
90.0,   6.9098, 9.5106
120.0,  13.09,  9.5106
150.0,  18.09,  5.8779
180.0,  20.0,   0.0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{testdata.csv}{\table}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    dec sep align=S,    % Use the siunitx `S` column type for aligning at decimal point
    fixed zerofill,     % Fill numbers with zeros
    precision=4,        % Set number of decimals
    display columns/0/.style={
        precision=1,    % Change for first column (column index 0)
        column name=$\theta_{2,i}$
    },
    display columns/1/.style={column name=$X$},
    display columns/2/.style={column name=$Y$},
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    ] {\table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One question, why I can't name any column like `column name=$i$`? I think that `siunitx` package think it's a complex number or..

Comment: You can use `${i}$` instead, to hide the imaginary unit from `siunitx`.

Answer (score 9):

There's no problem to do this with the `datatool` package and `siunitx` as well.  Here's your example done in that way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for nicer tables
\usepackage{caption} % improve caption spacing (among other things)
\usepackage{bm}
\renewcommand*\dtldisplaystarttab{\toprule}
\renewcommand*\dtldisplayendtab{\tabularnewline\bottomrule}
\renewcommand*\dtldisplayafterhead{\midrule}

\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb
 [
    noheader,
    keys={x,y,theta},
    headers={
    \shortstack{$\boldsymbol{\theta_{{2,i}}}$},
    \shortstack{X},
    \shortstack{Y}}
  ]
  {db}{db.txt}
\begin{table}[t]
\sisetup{
    parse-numbers   = false,
    table-number-alignment = left,
    table-figures-integer = 4,
    table-figures-decimal = 4,
    input-decimal-markers = .
    }
    \renewcommand*\dtlrealalign{S}
  \caption{Database file}
  \centering
  \DTLdisplaydb{db}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]