# Convert numpy array into tabular

Tags: tables, arrays, pgfplotstable

I am doing some data analysis in python, putting the results in form of a matrix stored into a numpy array. I would like to put this results into a report and the best way would be to put a table with a tabular inside containing the data.

Is anyone aware of a quick way to output latex code from python, or any other way I could use to quickly format an array into a tabular code latex can handle ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you use something like `print " & ".join([str(entry) for entry in row])` for each row? Here, row is a vector of numbers.

Comment: @Yori thanks! I used something like this before seeing Paulo's and Mike's answers and it worked.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's been a while since I played with NumPy, but I used to call the `numpy.savetxt` function to export my data as a `.csv` format:

```python
import numpy
A = numpy.random.randn(4,4)
numpy.savetxt("mydata.csv", A)
```

The sample file `mydata.csv` was generated accordingly:

```
1.058690791897618361e-01 4.236767150069661314e-01 -9.871862191240249329e-02 1.896410657805123634e+00
-3.688082441801866507e-01 -6.185162583308108086e-01 7.779589745526608313e-01 -1.718082361568575633e+00
-2.750126418674324058e-01 1.636150392013778487e-01 -5.227282169549336555e-01 6.038835633452429574e-01
-1.113971762033877821e+00 -1.572603551712207670e+00 -6.206581544211196011e-01 -1.960843071998005893e+00
```

With the magic of `pgfplotstable`, we could do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[dec sep align,
   fixed zerofill,
   precision=4,
   col sep=space]{mydata.csv}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output 1]

I don't know if it's possible to remove the headers, but in any case I'll ask Christian Feuersänger about it. `:)`

My good friend [percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235) provided a nice way of removing those headers:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
   fixed zerofill,
   precision=4,
   col sep=space,
   dec sep align,
   columns/0/.style ={column name=},
   columns/1/.style ={column name=},
   columns/2/.style ={column name=},
   columns/3/.style ={column name=},
]{mydata.csv}
```

Another, well, "way" of doing it is by tricking `numpy.savetxt` to act as:

```python
numpy.savetxt("mydata.csv", a, delimiter=' & ', fmt='%2.2e', newline=' \\\\\n')
```

which will give us the following output file:

```
1.21e+00 & 3.52e-01 & -5.53e-01 & 7.28e-01 \\
-1.61e+00 & 6.72e-01 & 5.75e-01 & -1.00e+00 \\
3.60e-01 & 1.68e-01 & -1.65e+00 & 2.10e-01 \\
5.73e-01 & -7.29e-03 & 1.65e+00 & -1.37e+00 You could remove the last `\\` and paste it inside a `tabular` enviroment. And thanks to `siunitx`, we get a nice formatting:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{SSSS}
    1.21e+00 & 3.52e-01 & -5.53e-01 & 7.28e-01 \\
    -1.61e+00 & 6.72e-01 & 5.75e-01 & -1.00e+00 \\
    3.60e-01 & 1.68e-01 & -1.65e+00 & 2.10e-01 \\
    5.73e-01 & -7.29e-03 & 1.65e+00 & -1.37e+00
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output 2]

At last but not least, `datatool` can also be used. Unfortunately, it seems that `datatool` does not recognize scientific notation as real values, so it treats like a string value. To fix it, I exported my `.csv` file with a comma as delimiter and with fixed-point values:

```python
numpy.savetxt("mydata.csv", a, delimiter=',', fmt='%2.2f')
```

which will generate the following output:

```
1.24,-0.96,-1.51,-0.21
0.93,-1.37,0.30,-0.89
0.33,-0.16,-1.27,-0.02
1.08,1.22,0.29,0.15
```

Now, our LaTeX code, based on [Alan's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44400/3094):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={0,1,2,3}]{db}{mydata.csv}

\begin{table}

  \sisetup{%
    parse-numbers=false,
    table-number-alignment=left,
    table-figures-integer=4,
    table-figures-decimal=4,
    input-decimal-markers={.}
  }
  \renewcommand*\dtlrealalign{S}

  \centering
  \DTLdisplaydb{db}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output 3]

By using `\DTLdisplaydb`, headers are mandatory. If you don't want them, you can iterate through the values of the `.csv` value instead.

You can obtain more information on those packages by searching their tags: [siunitx](/questions/tagged/siunitx), [datatool](/questions/tagged/datatool), [pgfplotstable](/questions/tagged/pgfplotstable)

Thanks to Jake, percusse and Alan. `:)`

Comment: you can add `every head row/.style={typeset cell/.style={}},` as option to `\pgfplotstabletypeset`. This will omit the header row. In fact, it will omit an empty header row. I will think about a suitable style which makes this accessable in a simpler way.

Answer (score 38):

Working from [[SciPy-User] 2d array to Latex](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2010-January/023946.html):

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 26 2010, 22:31:48)
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> a=numpy.zeros((2,2))
>>> print " \\\\\n".join([" & ".join(map(str,line)) for line in a])
0.0 & 0.0 \\
0.0 & 0.0
>>>
```

Add on tabular, table, and other environments or commands as needed.

Comment: Beautiful solution, Mike! `:)`

Answer (score 28):

There is a python package called `tabulate` that can directly output latex tabulars. You can find it on pypi [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate).

An example would be the following

```
import scipy
from tabulate import tabulate

a = scipy.random.rand(3,3)

print(tabulate(a, tablefmt="latex", floatfmt=".2f"))
```

which outputs something like

```
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
\hline
 0.97 & 0.48 & 0.76 \\
 0.56 & 0.52 & 0.86 \\
 1.00 & 0.11 & 0.25 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since `numpy.set_printoptions(precision=3)` didn't work for me in the combination with Mikes answer, here is a little upgrade which allows defining the precision.

```
a = np.zeros((2,3))
print " \\\\\n".join([" & ".join(map('{0:.3f}'.format, line)) for line in a])
```

The precision is changed by changing the `0:.3f` to the required number of digits.

Or for

Python 3

```
print(" \\\\\n".join([" & ".join(map('{0:.3f}'.format, line)) for line in a]))
```