# Datatool and multiple files

Tags: datatool

I am trying to achieve the same goal as I tried with pgfplotstable as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63256/long-table-and-pgfplotstable-with-multiple-data-files/63282#63282) for which I got good help from the author of pgfplotstable (Dr. Christian Feuersänger) himself. Hence this question may be considered to be of academic interest to me.

I have two csv files: `names.csv`

```
Sl. No., Reg. No.,Name,Category,Group,Gate,Sponsored,Department
1,MS001,Ajay-D-Vimal Raj P,PY,OBC,--,No,Physics
2,MS002,Harish Kumar,PY,GE,GATE,Yes,Physics
3,MS003,Ajay-D-Vimal Raj P,PY,OBC,--,No,Physics
4,MS004,Harish Kumar,PY,GE,GATE,Yes,Physics
```

and `marks.csv`

```
number,marks
MS001,67
MS002,25
MS003,62
MS004,55
```

**Requirement:** I want to print the first file (`names.csv`) into a long table in which, I would like to include the second column (i.e., marks column) of `marks.csv`, as the column coming after the names column (i.e., as the fourth column).

Here is the MWE (working, but not as I desired)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{datatool}
% \usepackage{filecontents}
%
% \begin{filecontents}{names.csv}
% serial,number,name,group,category,gate,sponsored,dept
%     1,MS001,Ajay-D-Vimal Raj P,PY,OBC,--,No,Physics
%     2,MS002,Harish Kumar,PY,GE,GATE,Yes,Physics
%     3,MS003,Ajay-D-Vimal Raj P,PY,OBC,--,No,Physics
%     4,MS004,Harish Kumar,PY,GE,GATE,Yes,Physics
% \end{filecontents}

% \begin{filecontents}{marks.csv}
%     number,marks
%     MS001,67
%     MS002,25
%     MS003,62
%     MS004,55
% \end{filecontents}
%
\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb{names}{names.csv}
\DTLloaddb{marks}{marks.csv}                       
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------%
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------%
{\small
\begin{longtable}{|c|l|p{3.5cm}|c|l|c|c|c|c|}\hline
% -----------------These are headings----------------------------------%
\textbf{} & \textbf{Reg. No.} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Name}} & \textbf{Marks}&
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Category}}  & \textbf{GATE} & \textbf{Sponsored} &\textbf{Department} \\ \hline
%
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{8}{c}%
{{\bfseries  Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
%
\textbf{} & \textbf{Reg. No.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Name}} & \textbf{Marks}&
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Category}}  & \textbf{GATE} & \textbf{Sponsored}&\textbf{Department} \\ \hline\hline
\endhead
%
\hline \multicolumn{8}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot
%
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|r|}{{Concluded}} \\ \hline
\endlastfoot
%-----------Headings end---------------------------------
%--------------------------table body starts-------------------
\DTLforeach{names}{%
\sl=serial, \reg=number,\name=name, \group=group, \category=category, \gate=gate,\sponsored=sponsored,\dept=dept}{%
\DTLiffirstrow{}{\\\hline}%  
% \DTLiflastrow{\dtlbreak}{}
% \DTLiffirstrow{\dtlbreak}{}
 \DTLforeach{marks}{%
 \marks=marks}{%
 \DTLiffirstrow{}{\\}%
%  \DTLiffirstrow{\dtlbreak}{}
% \DTLiflastrow{\dtlbreak}{}
\sl & \reg & \name & \marks & \group/\category & \gate & \sponsored & \dept
%
}%
}%
%--------------------------table body ends-------------------
\end{longtable}
}%
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

But somehow I am not able to get the looping correct and every name is repeated 4 times.

**Questions:**

1. How to get the corresponding mark from `marks.csv` file and print it. (get the `\DTLforeach` correctly?)
2. How to sort the resulting table in the increasing order of marks while keeping only the serial numbers in the first column untouched. (All other columns should be sorted as per their corresponding marks)?

Any more clarifications will be gladly obliged.

Comment: Every name is repeated four times with _four different marks_. That should be a clue as to where the looping is going wrong, right?

Comment: @Seamus: `\DTLforeach` is not the correct thing for that. I ran out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `LaTeX` is not designed as a DBMS and it is thus really ugly doing a join with it, using a match on the second `\DTLforeach` you will get the desired result:

```
\DTLforeach[\DTLiseq{\subnum}{\reg}]{marks}{%
 \subnum=number, \marks=marks}{%
```

But I strongly recommend using a dedicated DBMS to generate the table you like and only as a final step reading it into `LaTeX`. That way you won't need any such nested loops.

As for the second question the [`datatool` documentation](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-isdef) tells us in section 5.8 how to do it:

```
\DTLsort{number}{names}
```

just anywhere between loading the *names* db and displaying the data will do. Keeping the serials in their original order does not make sense to me. But if that is what you need, I would save the order before sorting and later read that. But if you only want a consecutive numbering of the rows, you can use a counter. Define it with `\newcounter{row}` and print every row with:

```
 \therow\refstepcounter{row}
 & \reg & \name & \marks & \group/\category & \gate & \sponsored & \dept
```

Comment: Thanks @canaaerus. It works. About serials, that is the need of the hour for me. Thanks for your time.