# Putting multiple columns from csv file into single column while printing the table using pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

**Reference:** My question which was answered by Dr. Christian Feuersänger [Link to the question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63256/long-table-and-pgfplotstable-with-multiple-data-files/63282#63282). This is a follow-up question.

The MWE (Provided by Dr. Christian Feuersänger in his answer)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  col sep=comma,
  columns/col1/.style={string type,column type=r},
  columns/col2/.style={string type,column type=l},
  columns/col3/.style={string type,column type=l},
  ]
{
    col1,col2,col3
    Col A,B,C
    The first column,E,F
}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Question:** 
How to get a table having only two columns with second column having the elements

```
col2/col3
B/C
E/F
```

In detail, the table should be like this:

```
    col1               col2/col3
    Col A              B/C
    The first column   E/F
```

How to get it using pgfplotstable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to create a new column based on existing ones, you have to define the new column somehow. This involves three steps:

1. defining how the new column should be defined (i.e. define its content): `create one use`
2. tell `pgfplotstable` that it should be part of the output (and at which position) : `columns` key
3. modify the appearance options of the new column: `column/<name>/.style={...}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  col sep=comma,
  columns/col1/.style={string type,column type=r},
  columns/col2/.style={string type,column type=l},
  columns/col3/.style={string type,column type=l},
  columns/mixed/.style={string type,column type=l,column name={col2/col3}},
  columns={col1,mixed},
  create on use/mixed/.style={
    create col/assign/.code={%
        \edef\entry{\thisrow{col2}/\thisrow{col3}}%
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
    }
  },
  ]
{
    col1,col2,col3
    Col A,B,C
    The first column,E,F
}   

\end{document}
```

The new lines are those which refer to `mixed` (which is my name for the new column).

The line `columns={col1,mixed}` tells `pgfplotstable` that which columns should be typeset (and in which order), i.e. it fulfills step (2).

The line `columns/mixed/.style=...` configures appearance options for column `mixed` (including its display name), i.e. it fulfills step (3).

Finally, the `create on use/mixed/.style={...}` statement defines how to create the new column (step (1). In our case, we provide a `/.code` fragment which uses two programming constructs to define the content: The line `\edef\entry...` means "define `\entry` to the expanded value in the braces (expanded def)". The `\thisrow{colname}` statement expands to the value of `colname` in the currently processed row (there is also `\nextrow{colname}` and `\prevrow{colname}` which operate in a similar way). Finally, `\pgfkeyslet{.../next content}\entry` writes the value of `\entry` into some value which is expected by the `create col/assign` method as output.

Comment: Thank you Dr. @Christian Feuersänger. That served the purpose.