# pgfplotstable: Two columns into one with numeric data, but can't round

Tags: pgfplotstable

**Question:** Relates to the question posed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63381/putting-multiple-columns-from-csv-file-into-single-column-while-printing-the-tab). I have made one column from two, but I would like to round the numbers off from a precision of 4 to 2. How do I do that?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&,header=true]{
var & mean & sd \\
x & 95.265 & 11.4801 \\
y & 85.7 & 18.95 \\
z & 15 & 5.01 \\
}\means

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  columns/var/.style={string type},
  columns/mean/.style={fixed zerofill,precision=2},
  columns/sd/.style={fixed zerofill,precision=2},
  columns/mixed/.style={string type,column type=l,column name={Mean (SD)}},
  columns={var, mixed},
  create on use/mixed/.style={
    create col/assign/.code={%
      \edef\entry{\thisrow{mean} (\thisrow{sd})}%
      \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
    }
  }
]\means    \end{document}
```

The column "Mean (SD)" in the output is in the raw data format, even though I had specified the precision in the columns of "mean" and "sd". How do I get it to round off appropriately with zerofill?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your code, you're setting the number printing options for the two *output* columns `mean` and `sd`, but you're not actually printing them (you're only printing the columns `var` and `mixed`). Within the `mixed` column, you're not passing the numbers through the number formatting routine, but inserting them directly from the source table. Replacing `\thisrow{mean}` with `\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill, precision=2]{\thisrow{mean}}` and `\thisrow{sd}` with `\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill, precision=2]{\thisrow{sd}}` will lead to the desired result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&,header=true]{
var & mean & sd \\
x & 95.265 & 11.4801 \\
y & 85.7 & 18.95 \\
z & 15 & 5.01 \\
}\means

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  columns/var/.style={string type},
  columns/mixed/.style={string type,column type=l,column name={Mean (SD)}},
  columns={var, mixed},
  create on use/mixed/.style={
    create col/assign/.code={%
      \edef\entry{\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill, precision=2]{\thisrow{mean}} (\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill, precision=2]{\thisrow{sd}})}%
      \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
    }
  }
]\means    \end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! I was getting frustrated with that.