# Pgfplotstable without headings row

Tags: pgfplotstable

I would like to typeset a table with a multicolumn heading *only*.
Here is my current attempt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=&, header=false,
every head row/.style={
before row={%
\toprule
Facteurs & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Niveaux}\\
}},
every last row/.style={
after row=\bottomrule},
display columns/0/.style={string type}
]
{%
\pgfutilensuremath{\chi} & 8 & 11 & 14 & &
5 & 8 & 11 & 14 & 45 & 2.456
q & 8 & 11 & 14 & & 3
x & 8 & 11 & 14 & 5612345 & 4
b & 8 & 11 & 14 & & 5
}
\end{document}
```

which gives the following result:

[image]

How can I remove the headings row circled in red in the picture?

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54990/convert-numpy-array-into-tabular/54997#54997 and http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3525119&group_id=224188&atid=1060659

Comment: This seems too contain the solution indeed but I failed to make it work though.
if I understand correctly, I should install a new developement version of pgfplotstable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starting with version 1.6 of PGFPlots (I think), a new key `output empty row` has become available that suppresses printing of a row. This can be used in your style:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=&, header=false,
    every head row/.style={ 
        output empty row,
        before row={%
            \toprule
            Facteurs & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Niveaux}\\
        }
    },
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule
    },
    display columns/0/.style={string type}
]
{%
\pgfutilensuremath{\chi} & 8 & 11 & 14 & &
5 & 8 & 11 & 14 & 45 & 2.456
q & 8 & 11 & 14 & & 3
x & 8 & 11 & 14 & 5612345 & 4
b & 8 & 11 & 14 & & 5
}
\end{document}
```

---

If you're using an earlier version and can't / don't want to update, here's a slightly brutish workaround. You can add the code

```
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/table/omit header/.style={%
        /pgfplots/table/typeset cell/.append code={%
            \ifnum\c@pgfplotstable@rowindex=-1
                \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\pgfutil@empty%
            \fi
        }
    }
}
\makeatother
```

in your preamble, which makes a style `omit header row` available. If you use that key in `\pgfplotstable`, the output routine for each table cell will be amended with a check whether we're in row number `-1` (the header row), and if we are, no output is generated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/table/omit header/.style={%
        /pgfplots/table/typeset cell/.append code={%
            \ifnum\c@pgfplotstable@rowindex=-1
                \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\pgfutil@empty%
            \fi
        }
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=&,
    header=false,
    every head row/.style={
        before row={%
            \toprule
            Facteurs & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Niveaux}\\
        }
    },
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule
    },
    display columns/0/.style={string type},
    omit header
]
{%
\pgfutilensuremath{\chi} & 8 & 11 & 14 & &
5 & 8 & 11 & 14 & 45 & 2.456
q & 8 & 11 & 14 & & 3
x & 8 & 11 & 14 & 5612345 & 4
b & 8 & 11 & 14 & & 5
}
\end{document}
```