# How to switch row/column in a stacked bar chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

This is my MWE:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{ % Read the data into a table macro
Label   First   Second  Third
Yes      0.1     0.3     0.3
No      0.9     0.7     0.7
}\datatable

\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked, % Stacked horizontal bars
    xmin=0, % Start x axis at 0
    ytick=data, % Use as many tick labels as y coordinates
    yticklabels from table={\datatable}{Label} % Get the labels from the Label column of the \datatable
]
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x=First, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable}; % Plot the "First" column against the data index
\addplot [fill=green!70!blue] table [x=Second, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\addplot [fill=red!80!yellow] table [x=Third, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This script generates a chart in which y-axis corresponds to Yes/No values for columns *First*, *Second*, and *Third*. How do I change the script so that y-axis corresponds to columns (i.e., *First*, *Second*, and *Third*)? I need to represent the Yes/No distribution for a specific column horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by [transposing the table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288547/table-transpose) and modifying the script as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{ % Read the data into a table macro
Label First Second Third
Yes 0.1 0.3 0.3
No 0.9 0.7 0.7
}\datatable

\pgfplotstabletranspose[string type, colnames from=Label, input colnames to=Label]\datatabletransposed{\datatable}

\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked, % Stacked horizontal bars
    xmin=0, % Start x axis at 0
    ytick=data, % Use as many tick labels as y coordinates
    yticklabels from table={\datatabletransposed}{Label} % Get the labels from the Label column of the \datatable
]
\addplot [fill=green!70!blue] table [x=Yes, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatabletransposed};
\addplot [fill=red!70!blue] table [x=No, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatabletransposed};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```