# What tools are there to make LaTeX more viable at work

Tags: automation, r, sweave, tools, metadata

I do data mining in R, Python and various object oriented languages. I like using LaTeX to present my results; either to myself (i.e. use them for result interpretation/analysis) or to send to colleagues.

What are tools are there that I can use to speed up the mass and automated production of results (tables and charts)? I know of `Sweave` which was a necessary condition for me to be able to justify LaTeX over an alternative of automatically generating HTML documents with my results. Without this I would not be able to use LaTeX in my work. What tools are there that I can use to make the 'next step' and leave HTML in the dirt once and for all?

I use `Eclipse` with `StatET` at the moment.

Comment: related: [Convert `numpy` array into `tabular`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54990/convert-numpy-array-into-tabular)

Comment: [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) can also be helpful for integration between R and LaTeX

Comment: I also use `Hmisc` `latex` function

Answer (score 3):

Use the `RStudio` editor. This program allow to start  with a basic `.Rnw` document, insert and run R chunks or obtain directly the PDF with one click, without compiling yourself the intermediate `.tex` file. RStudio can work with both `Sweave` and the `knitr` package.  This is explained better  in the [RStudio documentation](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/).

Use `xtable` R package  to obtain LaTeX tables. For example, to show 
a dataframe `foo` as a LaTeX table you only need this chunk:

```
<< Example,echo=F,results=tex >>=      

library(xtable)

xtable(foo, caption="An example")

@
```

Insert chunks with figures (with the option `fig=T`) in `figure` floats. Captions and plain text can include `\Sexpr{}`, so you can automatize in some extent even the LaTeX text creation through R.

Comment: This can also be achieved with `latex()` from package `Hmisc` (only if you didn't already know .. but `xtable` is great as well)

Comment: @user2763361, I know that but I forgot to mention. Good point.

Answer (score 2):

[PythonTeX](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex) allows you to execute Python code in LaTeX documents and access the output.  The result is similar to Sweave.  It allows user-defined sessions that run in parallel and are cached automatically, to optimize performance.  The package also supports running Julia and Ruby code.  In principle, it should be possible add support for additional languages with minimal effort.

Answer (score 0):

[Lena](https://lena.readthedocs.io/) is an architectural framework for data analysis (I am its author). It is written in Python.

It allows to create many plots and tables without code repetition. It uses [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com) engine to render LaTeX templates from Python, and facilitates creation of PDF files (it calls `pdflatex` from Python's `subprocess` module) as well as PNG files (which you can use for HTML).

Among its features is that already created plots are not recreated (unless their template or data were changed). This is useful when you generate many figures.