# How do insert a pdf or excel spreadsheet neatly?

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, excel

I have a rather complicated excel-spreadsheet with calculations.
I would like to insert this into my document so it looks quiet neat. It easily fits one page with title, caption, etc.
I tried converting it to pdf and using:

```
\section{Calculations}
\subsection{Preliminary Calculations}
\includepdf[pages={1},fitpaper=true,picturecommand={!h}] {../NominalCalculations.pdf}
```

However this does not give me the desired result.
It creates one page with the section title and subsection title, then leaves a massive amount of white space and creates a new page for the pdf file.
The pdf file has enough space to fit title and sectiontitle above it.
How do I get them on one page? How do I caption it as a table? How do I display the LaTeX document page number on the page?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you insert a pdf using `\includepdf` you are inserting a *page* not an image.  So if you want to insert the PDF as part of your document like an image, use `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package. Then the page will be a regular page of your document, and will be numbered correctly also.

Comment: Hmm is that the only way?
If so, how can I caption it as a table instead of a figure?

Comment: Just put the `\includegraphics` command inside a `{table}` environment.

Comment: But really you should probably not format tables in Excel but use LaTeX to do them. If you save the unformatted Excel data as a CSV file you can easily import it and format it using `pgfplotstable`. See [How typeset a numeric table from a CSV file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24256) and also also [Comprehensive list of tools that simplify the generation of LaTeX tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49414) and

Comment: I never use tables in Excel, however I was given this one and I have to include it in the report. Thank you guys