# Problem with a child-document within a table

Tags: input, include

I ran into a problem with the `\include`/`\input` command. I want to generate a table based on the child document `somedoc.tex`, which looks as follow

```
$$12.67$$ & $$6.18$$ & $$5.00$$ & $$60.33$$ \\
$$12.80$$ & $$0.00$$ & $$0.00$$ & $$64.22$$ \\
$$0.83$$ & $$22.88$$ & $$18.02$$ & $$16.32$$
```

My code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\center \small
\begin{tabular}{SSSS} \toprule      
{col1} & {col3} & {col3} & {col4} \\ \midrule

\include{"somedoc.tex"}

\\ \bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\raggedright 
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

The weird thing is that I can easily generate the document when I put in the text from the child-document directly. However, when I include it via `\include`/`\input` it makes an error. So, how should I include the text as a child-document?

In advance, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Not so sure if this is the right way to do it, look at `pgfplotstable` it might be better. See e.g [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24280/141947) for some example

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand how    pgfplotstable will solve this?

Comment: you should not have `$` (or `$$`) around the numbers if you are including them in an `S` column, you can not use `\include` in a table (it always forces a new page at the start and end of inclusion) It is possible to use `\input` but doing that in a tabular requires some care, `\center` should never be used as a command, you meant `\centering`

Comment: @A.joh `pgfplotstable` is able to read data from files, and you can customize column headers and so on. Which seems to be fairly what you want to do, isn't it ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You are totally right! However, that will not solve the problem

Comment: @A.joh why doesn't it solve the problem? I posted the result of those changes as an answer, isn't that the output you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

---

```
12.67 & 6.18 & 5.00 & 60.33 \\
12.80 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 64.22 \\
0.83 & 22.88 & 18.02 & 16.32
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering \small
\begin{tabular}{SSSS} \toprule      
{col1} & {col3} & {col3} & {col4} \\ \midrule
\relax\input{"somedoc.tex"}
\\ \bottomrule 
\end{tabular}

\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to use  "\relax" before "\input"?

Comment: @David Carlisle:  You are totally right! "\relax" is a solution to the case above. I marked this as a solution. Thanks for your answer. It is appreciated a lot!